# Make multilingual just one section of a opencart Shop?

Tags: php, opencart, multilingual

In a opencart project, our client **doesn't want** to add **multilanguage to all the shop**, just for a new section that i'm about to make (instead of selling in this section he wants to rent)

What choices Do i have?

Will opencart or any other plugin help me with this? or I'll have to get a little bit out of the framework and hardcode the language for the section?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess You are all alone in this.

But here are few advices how I would cope with that:

1. I would display the language switcher only in the new section
2. I would change the session's variable name (of selected language for this section) to something different (e.g. `$_SESSION['my_section_language']`) so that the language of the shop is not changed nor affected by the section's language being selected
3. all other functionality/logic as well as administration of languages will remain the same

This could be pretty simple to implement just with few changes to present logic (change language only when within the section, new session variable).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.. pretty much what i was guessing.. for now i just created two different views and should do the job, will see.. thanks!